# MS Access - Delta (change over x) Between Current and Previous Row

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, delta

I've been scouring both this website and google in general trying to find a solution to my problem, but all I seem to encounter is errors in my query.

I have a table called Survey with the fields Hole, Depth, Az, Dip.

```
Hole   Depth   Az     Dip
---------------------------
AB1     0      170    -77
AB1    150     166    -76.5
AB1    200     160    -75
AD1     0      350    -88
AD1    65      344    -87.6
AD1    89      340    -85.4
AB2     0      152    -66
AB2    135     150    -63.2
```

I need a query that will find the change in az over depth (between two rows) and the change in dip over depth (between two rows), but only for Holes that begin with 'AB'. So the final output should look something like this (with a single value instead of the formula):

```
Hole   Depth   DeltaAz            DeltaDip
-------------------------------------------
AB1    150     (170-166)/150       (-77--76.5)/150
AB1    200     (166-160)/50        (-76.5--75)/50
AB2    135     (152-150)/135       (-66--63.2)/135
```

I've tried a bunch of different possible queries that I found on here, but nothing has really worked. The closest I got was with the simple code below that I was using to test the first step (getting the difference between two rows). However, when it ran I would see the results and an error message `Only one record can be returned by this subquery`. When I clicked okay on the error, all my results disappeared.

```
SELECT Hole, Depth, [Az] - (
            SELECT TOP 1 Az 
            FROM Survey AS S 
            WHERE Survey.Hole = S.Hole AND S.Az < Survey.Az 
            ORDER BY S.Az DESC
            ) AS Diff
FROM Survey
WHERE (
    SELECT TOP 1 Az 
    FROM Survey AS S 
    WHERE Survey.Hole = S.Hole AND S.Az < Survey.Az
    ) 
    IS NOT NULL AND Hole LIKE 'AB*'
ORDER BY Survey.Hole, Depth, Survey.Az
;
```

Does anyone have a solution to help me out? I am using MS Access 2013.

Comment: Are there always 3 records per hole, or is it a variable amount?

Comment: It's a variable amount. It's actually more like 20-30 records per hole.

Answer (score 0):

:edit: apparently I have no research comprehension and row_number () isn't available in MS access and there aren't any great alternatives.

I am not 100% sure that this is *exactly* what you need, and I am sure it could be improved, but it should get you in the right direction.

The error message you're getting is because your subquery is returning more than one record -- even though you have specified "top 1", I believe the top clause isn't processed until after the result is returned, and when a subquery returns more than one record, it errors out. You can use row_number () to discretely return ONE record (which is what I have done below).

Try it online http://rextester.com/RBQ22368

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    --Get delta from 0 to 150 
    SELECT s1.hole
        ,s1.depth
        ,s1.az
        ,s1.dip
        --Create a row number for each hole (each hole starts at 1), ordered by the depth in ascending order (0,150,200 etc)
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY s1.hole ORDER BY s1.depth
            ) AS rn
        ,s1.az - s2.az / (s1.depth - s2.depth) AS DeltaAZ
        ,convert(DECIMAL(5, 2), s1.dip) - convert(DECIMAL(5, 2), s2.dip) / (s1.depth - s2.depth) AS DeltaDip
    FROM survey s1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT hole
            ,depth
            ,az
            ,dip
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY hole ORDER BY depth
                ) AS rn
        FROM survey
        ) s2
        --Using the same row number calculation as above, we can specific exactly which record to return. Because we have explicitly defined how to calculate the row number, 
        --we know 1 will always be the lowest depth (0), therefore 2 will be the second lowest 
        ON s1.hole = s2.hole
            AND s2.rn = 1 -- Return the first result, which is the lowest 
    WHERE left(s1.hole, 3) = 'AB1' 
    ) s1
WHERE s1.rn = 2 --Limit the result to the second highest depth, since that's what you showed on your question (depth = 150)

--Using the same logic, but different row numbers, run the same result again as a union
UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT s2.hole
        ,s2.depth
        ,s2.az
        ,s3.az AS s2az
        ,s2.dip
        ,s3.dip AS s2dip
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY s2.hole ORDER BY s2.depth
            ) AS rn
        ,s2.az - s3.az / (s2.depth - s3.depth) AS DeltaAZ
        ,convert(DECIMAL(5, 2), s2.dip) - convert(DECIMAL(5, 2), s3.dip) / (s2.depth - s3.depth) AS DeltaDip
    FROM survey s2
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT hole
            ,depth
            ,az
            ,dip
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY hole ORDER BY depth
                ) AS rn
        FROM survey
        ) s3
        ON s2.hole = s3.hole
        --This time, we will compare the 3rd result with the second result. 
            AND s3.rn = 2 -- only return the second record
    ) s2
WHERE s2.rn = 3
    AND left(hole, 2) = 'AB'
ORDER BY s1.hole
    ,s1.depth
```